# Compiling FFmpeg : libx264 not found

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, libx264

I hope some one helps me the solve this problems. I was trying to compile FFmpeg 2.2.3 library under ubuntu 12.04LTS for android using android ndk r10e by following this tutorials:

[Tutorial1](http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/)

[Tutorial2](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

here is my build_android.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86

#ADDI_LDFLAGS="-L /usr/local/lib"
#ADDI_CFLAGS="-I /usr/include"

function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--enable-protocol=concat \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-muxer=mp4 \
--enable-demuxer=mpegts \
--enable-memalign-hack \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264 \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic -marm $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \

make clean
make -j4
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU

build_one
```

when i execute buid_android.sh script without --enable-libx264 \ line everything is going well and i can get .a files on android/arm/ folder. but with this line it fails and show the following error in the console:

> ERROR: libx264 not found
>
> If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the
>   latest version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the
>   problem to the ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on
>   irc.freenode.net. Include the log file "config.log" produced by
>   configure as this will help

it seems like it can't find where the libraries are, as i get a lot of the following errors in config.log file:

> "LIBNAME".h: No such file or directory
>   newlib.h: No such file or
>   directory mingw.h: No such file or directory
>   x264.h: No such file or
>   directory

Here is the tail of config.log file:

```
check_mathfunc truncf 1
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
    1   #include <math.h>
    2   float foo(float f, float g) { return truncf(f); }
    3   int main(void){ return (int) foo; }
END /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -isysroot /home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -Os -fpic -marm -march=armv5te -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -marm -pthread -c -o /tmp/ffconf.8Q9ke3aO.o /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -isysroot /home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -Wl,--as-needed -o /tmp/ffconf.3sjTkc5z /tmp/ffconf.8Q9ke3aO.o -lm -lz -pthread
check_lib x264.h x264_encoder_encode -lx264
check_header x264.h
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
    1   #include <x264.h>
    2   int x;
END /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -isysroot /home/rango/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/ -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -Os -fpic -marm -march=armv5te -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -marm -pthread -E -o /tmp/ffconf.8Q9ke3aO.o /tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c
/tmp/ffconf.zGKqGin6.c:1:18: fatal error: x264.h: No such file or directory
 #include <x264.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
ERROR: libx264 not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically to build *FFmpeg* for *Android* with *libx264* support you need to go through these steps:

1) Build *libx264* for *Android*. Now you haven't any built *libx264*, that's why you get above error.

2) Change your *buid_android.sh* and add additional options to *configure* (`--extra-cflags` and `--extra-ldflags`) to specify paths to `include` and `lib` directories of *libx264* which was built on step 1.

3) Run modified *build_android.sh*.

Unfortunately, I haven't built *libx264* for `Android`. But I assume that there're ways to do it...

Comment: thank you for the answer. i already solved it the problem is i should compile libx264 for android as you said using android cross compiler and not with one of the system. i compiled it now and its working. i will post a complet answer with every step i did to get it work soon

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what i did to get to compile correctly. as Edgar mentioned i should have compiled libx264 library for android using the NDK compiler.
i used this script to get it done.

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=(path to android ndk)/android-ndk-r10e
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86



./configure --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--enable-static \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static \
--disable-cli \
--disable-asm \
--extra-cflags="-fPIE -pie" \
--extra-ldflags="-fPIE -pie" \
--host=arm-linux

make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Why would you `--disable-asm`?

Comment: I don't actually know why this option exist there, i just copied it somewhere else.

Comment: Disabling ASM can make encoding slower.

Comment: Yes i noticed that encoding is too slow after compiling it. i will try compiling with asm .